# Who has some insights on watching Netflix

Tags: chromium, netflix

I have tried running both Firefox and Chromium. Both state I need to run Microsoft Silverlight to watch. Can't put Silverlight in Ubuntu. Does anyone have any links I can check to get more detailed instruction? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you can't using Chromium or Firefox.  Do note they are dropping support for Silverlight too, and are moving to HTML5 with DRM (Digital Rights Management).  This DRM is not included in current Chromium or Firefox builds.  It is in Google Chrome.

For now, the "solution" is to install Google Chrome and use that.

Normally, the next big release of Firefox should also include the DRM libraries for Linux.  It's a matter of time.

---

As per comment below (Deleted?).  Go to https://www.google.com/chrome/ and click the "Download" button, Select the ".deb" option, then click "Accept and install".  Wait for the download to finish and select "Open With - Software Install (default)".

Software installer now opens, click the "Install" button.  Normally, you will now be asked your password to elevate to root privileges.

Chrome will now be installed and can be launched.  Click the "Ubuntu" button, type "Chrome".  It will display "Google Chrome".  Click it to launch it.  Now visit the Netflix website and log in to access the catalog.